# GPG: Which key is GPG exactly using for encrypting and decrypting?

Tags: gnupg, pgp

Sometime back I installed GPG and been using it to encrypt files and text.

Command used to encrypt:

```
gpg -c file.zip > file.zip.gpg
```

Command used to decrypt:

```
gpg -d file.zip.gpg > file.zip
```

Till now, I didn't pay attention to which key, since I was backing up the .gnupg folder directly. Today I wanted to confirm that the key exists and is present in the folder. But unfortunately, in the private keys folder, it shows nothing.

Commands `gpg -c` and `gpg -d` are working just fine. I get a UI based pop-up for password every time.

But when I run

```
gpg --export-secret-keys --export-options backup --output private1.gpg
gpg: WARNING: nothing exported

OR

gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG
it also returns empty.
```

Now, in my `private-keys-v1.d` folder, there is nothing. I have the files `pubring.kbx`, `trustedb.gpg`, `random_seed`. How can I be sure that after a fresh installation, I will be able to decrypt my files?

Comment: If `gpg -K` returns output, private key is in the keyring _(`gpg -K` will list keys with private keys as primary: `sec` | subkeys: `ssb`, whereas `gpg -k` will list them as `pub` and `sub` respectively)_. As to what subkey is being used, it's whatever key is the first `[E]` key in the list - to encrypt with a different `[E]` subkey, specify the key to be used as `<key hash>!` _(the trailing `!` tells `gpg` to use that specific key)_. If you're signing and encrypting, the same applies, where the first `[S]` subkey listed is what's used for signing. I can create an answer, just not at the moment

Comment: General FYI: I always recommend best practice is to export the primary, and each subkey individually and together, as all should be passphrase protected with a strong passphrase of at least 16 characters at creation, using two each of uppercase, lowercase, numbers, and symbols. This is especially important for `keytocard`, as once used, the private keys are removed from the keyring permanently and there is no way to get them back if the hardware key is reset, lost, etc. Provided the keys are protected with a strong passphrase in line with the aforementioned, the passphrase is uncrackable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `-c` flag to encrypt files means that [gpg uses symmetric key encryption](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Operational-GPG-Commands.html#index-symmetric).

[Symmetric key cryptography](https://csrc.nist.gov/glossary/term/symmetric_cryptography) uses a single key (the [symmetric key](https://csrc.nist.gov/glossary/term/symmetric_key)) that you provide every time you encrypt or decrypt each file. As such, there is no need to have public and private keys. So, if you have never created a public/private key pair in the past (e.g. for [signing](https://csrc.nist.gov/glossary/term/digital_signature)) then you won't have any private keys; this is why (probably) exporting your secret (private) keys return an empty set.

Note that symmetric keys are not stored anywhere, only cached<sup>1</sup> for user experience. So, you can't actually export them from anywhere.

---

<sup>1</sup> from the manual page, linked above: "*gpg caches the passphrase used for symmetric encryption so that a decrypt operation may not require that the user needs to enter the passphrase*"

Comment: I am not passing it any keys, If that would be the case, I would have backed up the key. So, incase I clean the current OS, even backing up the .gnupg directory won't help?

Comment: So, the passphrase passed is just tried and gpg checks if it can decrypt it with the password? Is that safe?

Comment: @WeareBorg: It's how most password-based encryption systems work; the same method is also used to encrypt your private key in ~/.ssh/id_rsa or in private-keys-v1.d if you have one. The passphrase is transformed into a key of the desired size using a KDF (similar to hash algorithms but more designed for this purpose; PBKDF2 and Argon are popular). A good KDF will produce reasonably strong keys, and (unlike basic hashes) will be sufficiently slow to deter brute-force guessing of the passphrase. PGP/GnuPG's "S2K" KDF is not great but also not horrible, so it's safe if your passphrase is strong.

Comment: @WeareBorg: Overall that _is_ something that would be on-topic for Information Security SE, I think.